Javascript pasar el valor actual de un input range a CSS animation-duration
Tengo un indicador de progreso circular, que gira 360 grados mediante una animación, a una velocidad por defecto (animation-duration) de 6 segundos de duración, quiero aumentar la velocidad de giro mientras cambio el valor del input type=range. En resumen: el círculo girará más o menos rápido mientras cambio el desplazador del input range


let ring = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
let spd = document.getElementById("speed");
function masVelocidad() {
    ring.style.animationDuration = spd.value + "s";
}
alert(spd.value + "s");

//Otras pruebas

/*spd.addEventListener('input', () => {
  ring.style.animationDuration = spd.value + "s";
})*/
.circle {
        border: 9px solid rgb(48, 47, 47);
        border-top: 9px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        animation: 6s linear 0s infinite loader;
    }
<div class="res">
            <h2>Resultado</h2>
            <hr>
            <div id="container">
                <h3>Progreso de la Carga</h3>
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <p>Cargando...</p>
            </div> <!-- End #container -->
            <label for="veloz">Velocidad: </label>
            <input type="range" min="4" max="20" value="6" name="veloz" id="speed" onchange="masVelocidad()">
            <hr>
        </div>




Según interpreto de los mensajes en los depuradores, no llego hasta la propiedad animation-duration en el archivo CSS, por lo cual ellos la ven indefinida (Undefined). Quizás tenga que utilizar otro método de acceder a esta propiedad, como por ejemplo utilizar un documento de estilos en el "window" del DOM. Ya he probado con el método setAttribute y tampoco me ha funcionado. El problema está en que le estoy asignando un valor a una propiedad CSS a la cual no alcanzo con ningún método, al menos de los que conozco, creo yo que ese es el problema.

En tu primer código tenias:
<div class="circle"></div>
let ring = document.getElementById("circle");

Esto falla porque no tienes ningún elemento html cuya id sea circle.
Luego editaste y lo cambiaste por
let ring = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
//                            ↑
//   Notar la S en elementS, que quiere decir que está en plural
                              

¿Como debería ser?

let ring = document.getElementsByClassName("circle")[0];
//                                                   ↑ Nos referimos al primero que encuentre

//o también, puedes usar:
let ring = document.querySelector(".circle"); //no olvidar el punto como prefijo, porque nos referimos a una clase                                           

Yo por otro lado, simplemente usaría una id

Luego tienes otro problema, no puedes variar la velocidad de una animación directamente. Ese atributo no existe.
Puedes cambiar la duración que es distinto. A mayor duración la animación irá más lento y a menor duración irá más rápido (es decir, son inversamente proporcionales)
Por lo que al aumentar el input[type=range], el siguiente código
ring.style.animationDuration = spd.value + "s";

Aumenta la duración, disminuyendo la velocidad que es lo contrario a lo que tu quieres.
Aquí un ejemplo


let ring = document.getElementById("circle");
let spd = document.getElementById("speed");

function masVelocidad() {
  ring.style.animationDuration = (12 / spd.value) + "s";
}
.circle {
  border: 9px solid rgb(48, 47, 47);
  border-top: 9px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: loader 6s linear 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes loader{
   0% { transform: rotateZ(0); }
  100%{ transform: rotatez(360deg);}
}
<div class="res">
  <h2>Resultado</h2>
  <hr>
  <div id="container">
    <h3>Progreso de la Carga</h3>
    <div id="circle" class="circle"></div>
    <p>Cargando...</p>
  </div>
  <!-- End #container -->
  <label for="veloz">Velocidad: </label>
  <input type="range" min="6" max="20" value="1"  name="veloz" id="speed" oninput="masVelocidad()">
  <hr>
</div>




Gracias Yussef:  mira cuantos detalles se escaparon y cuantas cosas no sabia. Tengo que profundizar mas en ello. Gracias por hacérmelo ver :).

@webrollandeveloper Que bueno haber podido ayudarte, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si así te parece- Saludos

Después de probar, modificar y estudiar la acertada respuesta de Yussef, un detalle importante: tuve que mover la declaración del link del script, al final del body, por el hecho de que hacía solicitudes al DOM, sin este haber terminado de cargar toda la pagina.
